# How to make canvas tag fixed in position and not scroll with content?

Tags: html, css, canvas, tags

I have a simple html page setup with a canvas tag that covers the entire view, the content on top of such canvas tag is deeper so when I scroll the page I want to leave the canvas always visible and not scroll with the rest of the page, any help will be much appreciated

So far my research points me to how to make a background image using CSS fixed to its position but these techniques don't apply to a canvas tag, as far as I know

Comment: will need position:fixed, like any other tag html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use fixed position with **CSS** on the `canvas` tag:

```
canvas {
  position: fixed;
}
```